# VB.NET Handle event from one class in another without them knowing eachother...?

Tags: vb.net, events

I have an application.

Module1 - Main application

DataAccessMananger - Class in main application to handle data

Configuration - Class in a different project (common dll) that handles configuration settings.

The problem / Question. How can the Configuration class handle a data changed event in the DataAccessMananger without it knowing what a DataAccessManager is since they are in different classes?

The only way I can think of making it work is to have Module 1 handle the event from the DataAccessMananger and have it call a method in the Configuration class, however I dont like this, I would rather Configuration be able to handle its own data updates...

Clear as mud? Any ideas? VB.NET 4.5, and I know a bit about delegates, but not sure how I could use them here, they must be the answer some how...

Ideally, I would like to be able to pass an "Event" to the config class from the DAM class using the module...

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: Technically, when object1 handles an event of object2, what actually happens is that a delegate is created that refers to a method in object1 and that delegate is passed to object2, which stores it in a collection. Object2 raising the event actually consists of it going through that collection of delegates and invoking each one.  So, it's quite possible for your two classes to not know anything about each other and one of them still handle an event of the other, as long as there is some other type that knows about both of them and is able to create and pass the delegate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this unless you can modify and compile a new version of the Common.dll. From there you can create methods that would allow you to dynamically add event listeners. I'm afraid you're stuck with having your module subscribe to the event and calling a method in the Config class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of would be to add an interface in the configuration class (common.dll) that would be implemented by the DataAccessMananger. I assume the mainmodule is aware of both the DataAccessMananger and the Configuration, right ? If so, the following might be a solution.

1. Add an interface to common.dll for the Configuration class to use (not implement) that contains the event to be managed. For instance:

   ```
   Public Interface IConfiguration
       Event ConfigChanged(sender As Object, e As configPropertyChanged)
   End Interface
   ```

   In my case, I also create a class inheriting Event args.

   ```
   Public class configPropertyChanged
   Inherits EventArgs

       Public Property PropertyName() As string
       Public Property NewValue() As String
       Public Property OldValue() As String

       Public sub New(Newvalue as string,OldValue as string,<CallerMemberName()> optional PropertyName as string = "")
          Me.NewValue = Newvalue
          Me.OldValue =OldValue
          Me.PropertyName = PropertyName
       End sub
   End Class
   ```
2. The configuration class is then modified to be able to monitor any class (which means that in the main module, the configuration must be made aware of the DataAccessManager class (Notice Idisposable is implemented to cleanup).

   ```
   Public Class Configuration
   Implements IDisposable
      Private _ConfigList As New List(Of IConfiguration)

       Public Sub RegisterConfig(Config As IConfiguration)
           _ConfigList.Add(Config)
           AddHandler Config.ConfigChanged, AddressOf ConfigChanged
       End Sub

       Public Sub ConfigChanged(sender As Object, e As configPropertyChanged)
            Console.WriteLine("Config has changed.")
       End Sub

      #Region "IDisposable Support"
      Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls
      Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
          For Each config As IConfiguration In _ConfigList
          RemoveHandler config.ConfigChanged, AddressOf ConfigChanged
      Next
      _ConfigList.clear()
      End Sub
      #End Region

   End Class
   ```
3. DataAccessManager does implement the Iconfiguration interface (available from common.dll)

   ```
   Public Class DataAccessMananger
      Implements IConfiguration

      Public Event ConfigChanged(sender As Object, e As configPropertyChanged) Implements IConfiguration.ConfigChanged

      Private _Name As String
      Public Property Name() As String
       Get
          Return _Name
       End Get
       Set(value As String)
          If String.Compare(_Name, value, True) <> 0 Then
              RaiseEvent ConfigChanged(Me, New configPropertyChanged(Value,_Name))
             _Name = value
          End If
       End Set
     End Property
   End Class
   ```
4. Finally, the main module, which is the only one to be aware of the existence of both Configuration and DataAccessManager, register the DataAccessManager into the configuration.

   ```
   Public Sub Main()

      Dim MyManager As New DataAccessMananger
      Dim MyConfig As New Configuration
      MyConfig.RegisterConfig(MyManager)
      MyManager.Name = "New name"
   End Sub
   ```

In this scenario.
The main module load the configuration and the data access manager at some point and then, register the data access manager into the configuration object. It can also register any other class implementing the Iconfiguration process.

At some point, something triggers a raise event into the data access manager (In my example, changing the property name do exactly that). The data access manager raise the event, which the configuration object handles it since we registered the data class into the configuration object.

If you wanted, you could have skipped the interface entirely and just had the DataAccessManager raise an event to the main module, then in the main module event handler, call a public method from the configuration class.